# Using ViewFlipper instead of scroll down to load more

Tags: java, android, animation, viewflipper

I have a refreshable gridview that displays roughly 12 posts from my blog  with a footer that when clicked will load another 12 items vertically. Im trying to program it so theres an animation of flipping a page instead of just scrolling down more. Im currently looking into the ViewFlipper method however have no idea where to start =(. Any way someone can point me in the right direction?

Refreshable Gridview load more footer

```
private OnClickListener loadMoreClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!isLoadingMore) {
            isLoadingMore = true;
            footerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            refreshDelegate.startLoadMore();
        }
    }
};

public void onRefreshComplete() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    arrowImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    arrowImage.startAnimation(reverseRotateAnimation);

    headerRelativeLayout.setPadding(headerRelativeLayout.getPaddingLeft(),
            -1 * HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, headerRelativeLayout.getPaddingBottom());

    SimpleDateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String date=format.format(new Date());
    lastUpdateDateTextView.setText("Last Updated: " + date);

    isLoading = false;

    //show footer refresh button
    footerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void onRefreshStart() {
    headerRelativeLayout.setPadding(headerRelativeLayout.getPaddingLeft(),
            HEADER_TOP, 0, headerRelativeLayout.getPaddingBottom());
    headerTextView.setText(R.string.loading);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    arrowImage.clearAnimation();
    arrowImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    isLoading = true;

    //hide footer refresh button
    footerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (refreshDelegate != null) {
        refreshDelegate.startFresh();
    }
}

public void setOnRefresh(RefreshableInterface d){
    refreshDelegate = d;
}

public void onLoadingMoreComplete() {
    footerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    isLoadingMore = false;
}

}
```